# error "C1083 cannot open include file gecode/int.hh" although paths set correctly

Tags: c++, include, visual-studio-2015

using VisualStudio2015 Express  on Win8.1

I have set the location of my external include files
into project config / VC++ include dirs:
    $(VC_IncludePath);"C:\Program Files\Gecode\include"

Still the compiler says "C1083 cannot open include file gecode/int.hh"
when compiling:

```
#include <gecode/int.hh>
```

But it **can** find the file when I change C++ source code to:

```
 #include <C:\Program Files\Gecode\include\gecode\int.hh>
```

!!
Only the subordinate includes won't work then - and it's not a nice solution...

Other solutions proposed earlier  that **don't** work for me:

- removing .hh
- replacing <> by ""  after the include

Comment: Try placing quotes around the file in your project settings.  Your file path has spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is more than likely that your project setting's `include directories` does not accept (or treats strangely) file paths that have embedded spaces.

Thus you should place quotes around the name of the file path:

```
 $(VC_IncludePath);"C:\Program Files\Gecode\include"
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that double quotes don't make it work either.

Comment: Well, you should edit your question.  And if that doesn't work, you should verify that the include settings are indeed being recognized.  Either move the files to a directory that does not have spaces, or creating a directory alias (using maybe `subst`) and use that.  Then if that still doesn't work, the issue is more than likely that your include settings are not even being read, let alone not working.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was:
reverting VisualStudio version from 2015 to 2010
and applying patch VS10-KB983233-x86.exe
and entering the gecode-include-dir into:
  project properties / configuration / C/C++ /  AdditionalIncludeDirs

Not working: entering gecode path into prj / config / VC++ Dirs / IncludeDirs !!